# How to write Hebrew strings to a log file using log4j

Tags: java, log4j

How to write a Hebrew string to a log4j file. Right now I see `??????` in the file.

I have searched everywhere online to convert Unicode to string:

```
String abc = myStr.replaceAll("\u200F", "");
   abc = abc.replaceAll("\u200E", "");
   byte[] utf8Bytes = abc.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
   String value = new String(utf8Bytes);
   log.debug("value : "+ value );
```

I just need to write out a Hebrew string to a Log4j file in a readable format. Here is my configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R log4j.logger.testlogging=DEBUG 
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender     
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout     
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender     
log4j.appender.R.File=C:\\dri\\ums.log log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5     
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout     
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n log4j.appender.FILE.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you post your log4j configuration?

Comment: It is also possible your file reader cannot read the file correctly?

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
log4j.logger.testlogging=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=C:\\dri\\ums.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: the string is sent from an html form

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *Log4j file*? Is it a regular text log file that the `FileAppender` points to? Because I've tried printing Hebrew text right now and all is working out fine. I believe this is not a Log4j issue and might be related to your text reader.

Comment: Remove your calls to `abc.getBytes` and `new String`.  Forcing UTF-8 bytes to be displayed in the native charset is never going to be correct.  Just write `log.debug("value : " + abc);`.  All Strings in Java are designed to hold Unicode characters, including Hebrew.

Comment: log.debug("value : "+ value );  prints ?????? in the logfile.

Comment: The myStr variable set from input to the API.

Comment: log.debug("value : "+ abc ); prints ?????? in the logfile.

Comment: How are you examining the log file?  Are you viewing it in a command window in Windows, by any chance?

Comment: No I am opening the log file in notepad++

Comment: Is it a regular text log file that the FileAppender points to? Yes

Comment: My guess is that the log file is fine;  Notepad++ doesn’t know it’s a UTF-8 file.

Comment: @VGR I agree that that is the most likely cause. Still, the log file could very well be written to in ANSI format, presumably by Log4j. Then again his configuration clearly states that his encoding setting for the file appender is: `log4j.appender.FILE.encoding=UTF-8 `. In any case take a look at my answer and see if you can come up with a few ideas for me to add to it.

Comment: Which option is selected under the “Encoding” menu in Notepad++?  If it’s not “Encode in UTF-8”, what happens when you choose that?

Answer (score 0):

Based from what I've gathered from the comments and my own experience this is most probably not an issue with `Log4j` itself. I've posted a comment indicating just that:

> What exactly do you mean with Log4j file? Is it a regular text log file that the FileAppender points to? Because I've tried printing Hebrew text right now and all is working out fine. I believe this is not a Log4j issue and might be related to your text reader.

Other comments have confirmed their suspicion that it is your text reader that might be causing this issue. I was able to reproduce your issue by doing the following in `Notepad++`:

- Open a new tab in notepad++.
- Copy and paste [sample](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA) text containing Hebrew letters.
- `Language -> Convert to ANSI`

Text before the conversion:

`See also: אלף־בית‎ and אַלף־בית‎`

Text after conversion:

`See also: ???????? and ?????????`

Based on the code you provided *(assuming there is no shenanigans that we don't know for behind the scenes)* we can definitively conclude you are either writing to a file  that has it's encoding set to `ANSI` where all your special characters are being converted to question marks because they cannot be decoded or your characters are being read as `UTF-8` but merely displayed as `ANSI`.

> ANSI and UTF-8 are both encoding formats. ANSI is the common one byte format used to encode Latin alphabet; whereas, UTF-8 is a Unicode format of variable length (from 1 to 4 bytes) which can encode all possible characters.

I would recommend following these steps:

- Navigate to `Settings -> Preferences -> New Document -> Encoding` and make sure that the `UTF-8 (Apply to opened ANSI files)` option is selected.
- Close all your files currently opened in `Notepad++` and delete the log file. Make sure you are **actually** closing the files instead of just closing `Notepad++`. This should clear the file entries from cache and allow you to open them again with a different encoding.
- Run your Java application and let `Log4j` print to the file.
- Open the file with `Notepad++` and check that you are encoding in `UTF-8` by clicking on `Encoding` tab. If the option is not set to `UTF-8`, change it.
- If none of the above worked, please post further information in the comments.

Unfortunately I am not that well versed in encoding matters and had to look some stuff up in the process of writing this, so I can't help you as much as I would like to. However in addition to providing the steps above I can direct you to the following links which should provide you with further knowledge and *(consequently)* more insight into your problem:

- [Encodings And Character Display - Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Encodings_And_Character_Display)
- [ANSI to UTF-8 in Notepad++ - SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/762475)